# Matplotlib animation in for loop?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data by animation in a for loop. I want it to wait until the animation is finished and then proceed in the for loop. Pause seems to work to allow this but sometimes the movies are very long and I want to close and move to the next one. Anybody know how I can achieve this?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import time

for j in range(0,2):
 fig = plt.figure(j)
 mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
 mngr.window.setGeometry(j*256,0,256, 256)

 ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
 line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

 # initialization function: plot the background of each frame
 def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

 # animation function.  This is called sequentially
 def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i+j/4.))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

 # call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
 anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True,repeat=False)

 plt.pause(0.02*200)

 plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: add `plt.close()` right after `plt.pause(0.02*200)`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception to move to the next plot.
For better readability, move your plotting into a function:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import time



def animate_multi(j):
    fig = plt.figure(j)
    mngr = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    mngr.window.setGeometry(j*256,0,256, 256)

    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

    # initialization function: plot the background of each frame
    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    # animation function.  This is called sequentially
    def animate(i):
        x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
        y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i+j/4.))
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,

    # call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True,repeat=False)

    plt.pause(0.02*200)
    plt.close()
    plt.show(block=True)
```

Now, in your loop except `KeyboardInterrup` and continue to the next animation:

```
for j in range(5):
    try:
        print('Working on plot', j)
        animate_multi(j)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        plt.close()
```

**Note:**  You might have to press `<Ctrl>-<C>` twice to skip to the next animation.